# in Java how to get all possible distinct sums in an array

Tags: java, algorithm

All the possible distinct sums mean that the sums of any one, two, three to n(the length of the array) number in an array. 
    For example, if the given array is [2,2,3]
    the sums of one number in the array is the array itself [2,2,3]
    the sums of any two numbers in the array is [4,5]
    the sums of three numbers in the array is [7]
    Therefore, the result should be the combination of all possible sums, which is [2,3,4,5,7]
    Just the thoughts of the algorithm please, no need for specific code. Thank you

Comment: Simplest way would simply be to sum every sub-array of the array, and remove duplicates. Is the dataset too large for this to work?

Comment: Sorting the array should give you some information about potential ways to speed up the algorithm but @freeone3000's method is going to the core of it.

Comment: @freeone3000: sub-array would not work, in `[1, 2, 3]` you would not do 1+3, would you? Given that the OP needs that sum as well.

Comment: @AndreaAmbu That depends on how you define sub-array I read his comment as every array that is a subset of the main array that would include: the empty set, [1], [2], [3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3], and [1,2,3].

Comment: "Sub-array" in this case being derived from the mathematical subsequence. If 1,2,3 were a sequence, the subsequences would be "1, 2, 3", "1, 2", "1, 3", "1", "2", and "3". You won't get this with the Arrays.copyOf() method, but it should be fairly simple to write something to do this.

Comment: for a given array of size n there are `n choose 1`+ `n choose 2`+ ... + `n choose n` sub-arrays (not necessarily distinct). That gets very big very fast.

Comment: @freeone3000: if you have something _fairly simple_ to do that then just sum those and put them in a Set().

Comment: distinct sums, or sums of distinct subsets? this is an important distinction

Comment: FYI, @twain249, that sum happens to be exactly equal to 2^n.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Isn't that if you include `n choose 0`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to simply iterate through and take the sums and add them to a collection which does not allow duplicates.

Comment: you can't simply remove the duplicates first you have to handle them as they could have unique sums themselves (like in the OP example 2+2 is unique).

Answer (score 0):

Code as requested:

```
//following taken from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#Java
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> LinkedList<LinkedList<T>> BinPowSet(
        LinkedList<T> A){
    LinkedList<LinkedList<T>> ans= new LinkedList<LinkedList<T>>();
    int ansSize = (int)Math.pow(2, A.size());
    for(Integer i= 0;i< ansSize;++i){
        String bin= Integer.toString(i, 2); //convert to binary
        while(bin.length() < A.size())bin = "0" + bin; //pad with 0's
        LinkedList<T> thisComb = new LinkedList<T>(); //place to put one combination
        for(int j= 0;j< A.size();++j){
            if(bin.charAt(j) == '1')thisComb.add(A.get(j));
        }
        Collections.sort(thisComb); //sort it for easy checking
        ans.add(thisComb); //put this set in the answer list
    }
    return ans;
}
//use would be
Set<Integer> sums = new HashSet<Integer>();
LinkedList<Integer> powerList = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.<Integer>asList(arr));
for(Collection<Integer> sumEntry : BinPowSet(powerList)) {
    int x = 0;
    for(Integer y : sumEntry) {
        x += y;
    }
    sums.add(x);
}
return sums;
```

Note that duplicates **can** be removed. Addition is communitive, therefore any sum of the elements of the set that does not add a single element twice, taken in any order, will be present in the above.

Also note that while Guava's Sets.powerSet() was considered, it requires an actual Set as input, which will not allow duplicates (which were present in the example).

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the question as following.
First I would construct a function to compute the combinations.

combinations(Object[] A, int r)

This function would return me all nCr combinations from A, where n = A.length
Once I have this function in place I can call it for r=1, 2, 3... and print the sums.

Writing combination routine is a pretty standard technical interview question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StackOverflow {
static Set<Integer> tree=new TreeSet<Integer>();
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int [] array= {2,2,3};
    getAllSums(array,0,0);
    tree.remove(0);
    for (Integer i: tree)
        System.out.println(i);


}
public static void getAllSums(int[] numbersArray, int starting, int sum)
{   
    if(numbersArray.length == starting)
    {      
        tree.add(sum);    
        return;
    }
    int value = sum + numbersArray[starting];
    getAllSums(numbersArray, starting + 1, value);
    getAllSums(numbersArray, starting + 1, sum); 
}
```